# How to Filter data using lodash conditionally

Tags: lodash

How to get the ids as array from this list conditionally.
If the level is one then the user_id otherwise admin_id.

```
var users = [
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true  , level:1, 'user_id':'1', admin_id:'11'},
      { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false , level:2, 'user_id':'2', admin_id:'22'},
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true , level:1, 'user_id':'3', admin_id:'33'},
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true , level:2, 'user_id':'4', admin_id:'44'},
      { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true , level:1, 'user_id':'5', admin_id:'55'}
    ];
```

Expected array : **[1,22,3,44,5]**

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for here is either the native javascript [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) or lodash's [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map):

```
let result1 = users.map(user => user.level === 1 ? user.user_id : user.admin_id);

let result2 = _.map(users, user => user.level === 1 ? user.user_id : user.admin_id);
```